# Knockout + Ajax Content results in multiple binding error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, knockout.js

I have built a web application with multiple pages. Some of them are Knockout-driven.

I am trying to apply some Ajax-optimized page loading and stumble over the following issue.

Say I have the following general page structure

```
<body>
  <div id="content">
  </div>
</body>
```

And the following view, which is using Knockout. I include the call to applyBindings inline for being able to load the right ViewModel for every view.

```
<section id="editor">
  <ul data-bind="foreach: items">
   ....
  </form>
</section>

<script>
  ko.applyBindings({items: {}}, $("#editor").el)
</script>
```

I load the view asynchronously into div#content for example using JQuery.load("editor.html #content")

The first page load works fine, but when navigating away (again using JQuery.load) from this view and coming back again I receive the error:

```
You cannot apply bindings multiple times to the same element.
```

I have already tried to apply ko.cleanNode but with no success. What am I missing? The #editor node should be removed from the DOM when other content is shown. So I really do not understand how to clean bindings or reinitialize knockout.

Note: I do not want the old data, I want to initialize the Bindings like on a freshly loaded page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you test your `$("#editor").el` in console? It doesn't work in standard jQuery.

If your `$("#editor").el` returns undefined, your `ko.applyBindings({items: {}}, $("#editor").el)` is essentially binding to `window.document.body`.

You may try

```
ko.applyBindings({items: {}}, $("#editor").get(0));

...
// call cleanNode before loading new page.
ko.cleanNode($("#editor").get(0));
$("#content").load( "newpage.html" );
```

Comment: Wow, thanks. Indeed $("#editor").get(0) or shorter: $("#editor")[0] does the trick. I didn't dig into that direction because $("#editor").el worked at the first place.

Answer (score 0):

if your bindings in "editor" section doesn't change,i suggest you to load(AJAX) only json data from server,and replace(modify) your viewModel in the browser,in that way knockout will refresh the dom automaticly.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but as my #editor section is not preserved, i cannot simply reinitialize the view model; i have to re-apply bindings.